# How to click on Submit button from POP-UP window if submit button is available after scrolling page to down?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation

I am submitting a form value's through selenium and java. On the form initially I'm searching a product and selecting some values. Then it's showing a pop-up window with scroll to the pop up; see the first image.

[image]

Here I have to submit a form and for that I need to click on submit button. It's showing an error that "Element is not Visible". But when I scroll down to pop-up manually then submit button is available. As shown in below screenshot.
[image]

Is there any way that I have to scroll down page manually?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to aceess the pop up window beofore scrolling, else it may not work as intented.You need to use `JavascriptExecutor` for to scroll effect via scripts.
in order to use it see below snippets :

**Scroll down:**

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
```

**Scroll up:**

```
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, -250);");
```

Note the difference in scroll parameters.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can execute javascript code with [executeScript](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html).
Try something like this:

```
public void scrollDownAndClickSubmit() {
    executeScript("scroll(0, 250);");
    clickOnSubmitButton;
}
```